# Postgresql and cppcms

Tags: c++, postgresql, cppcms

I want to display from feed table some things like temperature_c/f and time on web because that i use with JavaScript and CppCms (C++ framework to web application)

I have an error and don't know how solve it.

This is a function from class feed.cpp after that function i got error

this method receive city id and session

```
    feed* feed::get_latest(cppdb::session* session, int c_id)
    {
       fprintf (stderr, "\nnum 0\n");
       int id = 0;
```

the id is int and autoincrement value, reference to `MAX(id)` this return query of a latest updating of the specific city

```
       cppdb::statement stat = (*session)<<"SELECT MAX(id) FROM city WHERE city = ?;" << c_id;
       fprintf (stderr, "\nnum 5\n");
       cppdb::result result = stat.row();
       fprintf (stderr, "\nnum 6\n");
       if (result.empty() || result.is_null(0))
       {
            return NULL;
       }

       id = result.get<int>(0);

       stat = (*session)<<"SELECT * FROM city WHERE id = ?;" << id;

       result = stat.row();

       if (! result.empty())
            return new feed(result, c_id, session);

       return NULL;
 }
```

There is the error

```
    main in rest api /city/5/feed/
    query string 
    method : GET

    num 0

    num 5 
    2014-08-12 18:28:19; cppcms, error: Caught exception [cppdb::posgresql: query execution failed : ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented
    ]
     (http_context.cpp:139)
```

Explanation:

I use this method (`fprintf (stderr, "\nnum 6\n");`) to find a error location. We are can see that error appear between num 5 to num 6.

Right here:

```
    fprintf (stderr, "\nnum 5\n");
    cppdb::result result = stat.row();
    fprintf (stderr, "\nnum 6\n");
```

how i can solve that ?

Comment: @Artyom, is this something you would like to look at?